# Problems with Google Calendars and iCal in Lion

Tags: macos, ical, google-calendar

I'm not sure WHY it is so hard to get calendar syncing to work right, but it does seem to be one of the problems of our age. I thought maybe finally with iCal 5 syncing with google calendars would finally just work, but no luck.

Main issue:

Everytime I delete an event, I get the message *"There was an error saving ical data. iCal encountered a critical error while saving to the database, and recent changes may be lost. More information may be available in the console."*

Console tells me:

*iCal: CoreData: warning: An NSManagedObjectContext delegate overrode fault handling behavior to silently substitute nil/0 for all property values for the object with ID '0x7fd8fc768b90 ' instead of throwing as recommended.*

This despite the fact I can't actually display my delegate calendars in iCal (they show up in the delegates tab, but I can't click the checkbox to show any of them), so the event I am trying to delete is in the "Main" calendar.

If I delete from the google side, it disappears no problems.

--

TLDR: gcal and ical won't play nice after Lion upgrade. Trouble deleting some events. Trouble adding any delegate calendars.

Comment: note: other reports here 
http://discussions.apple.com/message/16147043#16147043

Answer (score 3):

[BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com/) is the best answer I can give you if you only want to sync calendars to Google.

I would also highly recommend [SpanningSync](http://spanningsync.com/) which will also sync your Contacts in a much better and more reliable manner than Address Book will.

> (I have no affiliation with either company, and am a paying customer/user of both. I use/love BusyCal for my calendar, but I sync with MobileMe not gCal… I use SpanningSync to sync my contacts to Gmail. I have written reviews for both [Spanning Sync](http://tj.luo.ma/post/3738547193/syncing-google-contacts-and-mac-os-x-addressbook) and [BusyCal](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/10/22/busycal-info-panel-preferences-give-you-more-event-options/).)

Comment: so the best answer is not to use iCal? meh. CalDAV is not that complicated.

Comment: I bet the OP would disagree. It's also not just a matter of how "complicated" it is, but how much effort Apple puts into maintaining a functional relationship with Google's CalDAV implementation. Take Mail.app and Gmail craptastic IMAP implementation, for example. Sparrow is a much better option than Mail. The devs have a reason to care. Apple doesn't. In the past, it was better for them if you pay to use MobileMe. Same with iCal. Apple doesn't have any reason to care about gCal in iCal. BusyCal does. Their jobs depend on it.  The best answer is use the best tool for the job. That's not iCal.

Answer (score 1):

At the time Google stopped the possibility of deleting iCal events because of problems with iCloud which seemed to delete things from the google calender. Google already informed apple about this. 
Resetting iCal won't function until google reactivates the feature and apple fixes their iCloud bug.
Hope this issue will be fixed soon...

Here is the link to the known issues page:
http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs

Answer (score 0):

I will give it a try by resetting the whole iCal like explained.

You can follow the process explained on this article:
http://answers.makeitwork.com/how-to-reset-ical-on-your-mac-or-how-to-clean-up-your-ical/

Best,

Comment: thanks but no go. I actually did that article 1 up by trashing preferences and ~/Library/Calendars (since all my calendars live elsewhere as well). As soon as I re-add google calendar, get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I use iCal on three different computers to sync Google calendars from three accounts.  One of those accounts has two additional delegate calendars, for a total five Google calendars syncing with iCal.

I had a similar problem when I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion...  The solution I found was to simply delete the calendars from your comptuer(s) and then re-add them using the Internet Accounts section in System Preferences.

Haven't had a problem since.

Give it a whirl... let me know how it works for you.

Comment: well, glad to know it is working for some people! thanks, but I have tried adding/deleting multiple times and still get weird errors when deleting events and an unable to select delegate calendars

Comment: And I noticed that you have reset iCal (below)    Have you tried for giggles, to log into a different user account on your Mac, and set it up to sync iCal with Google Calendars.  I know if doesn't solve your problem, but it might get you on your way to determining if it's a problem with your user account.  I would be interested to know if you still experience the issues in a separate user account.