# Why does not Calendar.app sync to exchange calendar on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, calendar, ical, exchange-activesync

My problem is not [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142212/exchange-calendar-syncing-issue-on-maverics) or [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38844/ical-failing-to-sync-calendars-with-an-exchange-2010-based-server-ical-needs).

Error message: "*There was an error saving ical data. Calendar App encountered a critical error while saving to the database, and recent changes may be lost. More information may be available in the console.*"

It is very similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25082/problems-with-google-calendars-and-ical-in-lion).

However my console log has such entries:

```
09.11.15 11:54:53,484 CalendarAgent[2263]: CoreData: XPC: Token mismatch
09.11.15 11:54:53,485 suggestd[379]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.notifications] [There was an error when fetching NOBOs for principals: (Local) (error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134095 "(null)" UserInfo={Problem=request failed, store identifier mismatch})]
09.11.15 11:54:53,488 CalendarAgent[2263]: CoreData: XPC: Token mismatch
09.11.15 11:54:53,489 suggestd[379]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.notifications] [There was an error when fetching NOBOs for calendars: () (error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134095 "(null)" UserInfo={Problem=request failed, store identifier mismatch})]
```

When I setup my exchange account, first sync works good but after init sync it does not work anymore and I get this error. Well, when I deactivate my Exchange cal, delete all cache files and activate it again, it syncs for one time and then again not. But this is not a solution.

It seems like a bug - but I am not sure what to do now. Busycal costs 50€ and since Calendar.app is with Mac OS X, I thought they might fix this issue soon?

Answer (score 3):

I found these steps on the Apple site and modified them - the modifications work.

- open Calendar
- Calendar -> Accounts
- Disable exchange calendars
- **Reboot**

Now re-enable

- open Calendar
- Calendar -> Accounts
- Enable exchange calendars

Answer (score 2):

One way I've fixed Calendar syncing problems with Exchange and/or seeing the triangle warning sign is the following two steps (as alluded to in previous answers):

1. Close Apple Calendar and Apple Mail apps
2. In a Terminal run the following (which will kill any Calendar related processes and then remove the caches):

   > ```
   > pkill -f Calendar
   > rm ~/Library/Calendars/Calendar\ Cache*
   > ```

Then start the Calendar and it will pop up an info dialogue box saying it's rebuilding the caches and then it should work again..

Answer (score 1):

Since I [deactivated rootless](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) in my Mac OS X, calendar.app has no problems with sync to our Exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
After deleting the Calendar caches as explained earlier it was still not Synching properly.
Then I deleted all my Calendar items from the exchange account.
I use for this Outlook for Mac, but you can probably use anything, just be sure to delete EVERYTHING from the calendar.
It is now synchronizing perfectly between Mac Calendar, Outlook for Mac 2016, iPhone, etc.
A little note: before deleting every Calendar item, I did an .OLM export.
Unfortunately when I restore it back, it was missing a lot of appointment.
I strongly suggest before the deletion, to export them one by one as .ICS files and or manually write them down somewhere.
My best guess is that somewhere in the Calendar Exchange database there were a corrupted item, infact the OLM export-import will not work properly.
I hope it helps
Cheers